# How to create shortand for addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I want to create a shortand for addEventListener, the code I'm trying is:

```
var dom = {
  id: function(elementId) {
    return document.getElementById(elementId);
  }
};
dom.id.on = function(event, options) {
  var id = id.elementId;
  return id.addEventListener(event, function() {
  options;
}
}
```

When I use it like that:

```
dom.id('paragraph').on('click', dom.id('paragraph').innerText = 'clicked');
```

It instantly changes it's innerText to clicked, without I even clicking it.

Comment: What do you expect `options;` to do? You can’t pass an expression itself. You have to pass functions.

Comment: Why don't you just use jquery? Example: `$('p').on('click', function(p){p.innerText='clicked'}`

Comment: You are basically redevelopping jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `id` property, don't return the native element, but a *wrapper object* around the element that has an `on` method.

```js
var dom = {
  id: function(elementId) {
    const elm = document.getElementById(elementId);
    return Object.create(elm, {
      on: {
        value(event, fn, options) {
          elm.addEventListener(event, fn, options);
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

dom.id('foo').on('click', function() { this.textContent = 'done'; });
```

```html
<button id="foo">click</button>
```

Comment: Not working, it creates an type error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'elm.addEventListener')

Comment: Sounds like you aren't waiting for the element to exist in the DOM before running the script. Give your script the `defer` tag, or wrap it in DOMContentLoaded, or move it to the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! It's now working perfectly!

Comment: There's just one problem, it can not change te innerText, because dom.id returns the on function.

Comment: No, `dom.id` returns the underlying element *wrapped in an object* - so you can both use `.on` on what is returned, and you can also use native DOM methods on what is returned. `.on('click', () => dom.id('foo').textContent = 'foo')`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, when i click it, the console shows: TypeError: The Node.textContent setter can only be used on instances of Node

Comment: I guess it will need document.getElementById

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It looks like the `.textContent` setter doesn't like being invoked when the context contains the element in the prototype chain, but isn't the element itself. I'd use `this` instead, which'll refer to the element the listener was added to, see snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `dom.id('paragraph').innerText = 'clicked'` in a function:

```
dom.id('paragraph').on('click', () => {
  dom.id('paragraph').innerText = 'clicked';
}, options);
```

Comment: And what about `options;`?

Comment: No, that’s not what I mean. `options` isn’t a third argument to be added. The question defines `on` with `id.addEventListener(event, function() { options; }`, but `options;` doesn’t do anything. But there are more issues; everything is already considered in CertainPerformance’s answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of `options`?

Comment: The innerText does not change instantly, instead, it doesn't even change, I haven't checked console.